# How do I interact with a newly created server, created with child_process.spawn

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, steam

I'm trying to make a front-end for my privately hosted Counter-Strike Global Offensive servers, on the front-end when I hit run server, everything works great and the server starts up and logs to console. But how can I view information like the server IP address, players in the server, and other things?

This is what I have so far for running the server:

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var child = spawn('/home/steam/steamcmd/csgo/srcds_run -game csgo -console +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +host_workshop_collection 249376192 -tickrate 128 +maxplayers 20')
    child.stderr.on('data', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    child.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
    child.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {

    });

});
```

Like for e.g. if I used a paid server host I would have a control panel where I could see server IP, restart / stop view players in game and other things. I hope this was clear enough and sorry if it was poorly written. I'm not sure how else to word this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the server accept input once it has started? If so you can write to it using

```
child.stdin.write('my command\n');
```

Otherwise you're going to have to query it using something like [gamedig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gamedig)

Comment: Awesome thanks I couldn't for the life of me find something like Gamedig with all the googling I was doing. Though I suppose being able to host multiple servers with different IPs is impossible with only one VPS.