# Turn off CS:GO Dedicated Server via Node.js child_process

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam

I've been trying to programmatically control multiple Counter Strike: Global Offensive dedicated servers. Everything works fine, but I'm having trouble turning it completely off. When you turn on the server, it creates two processes: `srcds_run` and `srcds_linux`. I can easily do [child_process.kill()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal), and it will turn off the `srcds_run` process, but the `srcds_linux` process keeps on running, even when the server is off. If I try to kill **all** `srcds_linux` processes, then it will kill **all** of the CSGO servers, even if I'm trying to turn off only one. Is there any way to select the corresponding `srcds_run` and `srcds_linux` processes?

This is my code so far:

```
// Turns on the server if not already on

Server.prototype.start = function(callback) {

    if(!this.online) {

        // Turn server on
        console.log('Starting server');

        this.process = spawn(this.directory + '/srcds_run', ['-game csgo', '-console', '-usercon', '+game_type 0', '+game_mode 0', '+mapgroup mg_active', '+map de_dust2', '+sv_setsteamaccount ' + this.token], { cwd: this.directory});

        this.process.stderr.on('data', function(err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        });

        this.process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('stdin: ' + chunk);
        });

        this.process.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('stdout: ' + chunk);
        });

    }

    this.online = true;
    callback();
}

// Turns off the server if not already off

Server.prototype.stop = function(callback) {

    if(this.online) {

        // Turn server off
        console.log('Stopping server');
        this.process.kill();

    }

    this.online = false;
    callback();
}
```

I'm using an Ubuntu Server and am using the [child_process.spawn module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) on node.js

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: didn't expect to see something CS:GO related here xD

Comment: haha, yeah. I saw maybe [one or two threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071370/how-do-i-interact-with-a-newly-created-server-created-with-child-process-spawn) about this, but there isn't much

Comment: So is `srcds_run` spawning `srcds_linux`? Any chance it is a parent process of `srcds_linux`, and you can get its process id with `pgrep` or something similar? You should be able to get the process id of the original spawned process in node with [child_process.pid()](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_pid)

Comment: Thanks, dvlsg! That's exactly what I needed. I will post an answer below with the working code, once I get it up and running.

Comment: Hey this is pretty cool. What else can you do w/ Node js and CSGO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks to @dvlsg, I'm using `pgrep` to shut down the corresponding `srcds_linux` process. This is the code I have so far.

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var exec = child_process.exec;

function execute(command, callback){
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        callback(stdout, error, stderr);
    });
};


// Turns off the server if not already off

Server.prototype.stop = function(callback) {

    if(this.online) {

        // Turn server off

        console.log('Stopping server');

        var processId = this.process.pid;

        execute('pgrep -P ' + processId, function(childId, error, stderror) {
            console.log('Parent ID: ' + processId);
            console.log('Child  ID: ' + childId);

            this.process.on('exit', function(code, signal) {

                console.log('Recieved event exit');
                execute('kill ' + childId);
                this.online = false;
                callback();

            });

            this.process.kill();

        });

    } else {
        this.online = false;
        callback();
    }

}
```

I will update the code if I improve it, but this is what I have so far.